# Javascript input 'check' - why is the second 'checked' overwriting the first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, checkbox

I have a simple question that I'm hoping someone can solve for me.

I have some Javascript that is responsible for checking two seperate inputs, one after the other. However, it seems like only one of the inputs can be checked.

Whichever input's 'checking' I place first in the Javascript gets ignored or overwritten, and I have no idea why. Only the second input gets checked.

```
var radioButtonSticky = stickyATC.find('.swatch[data-option-index="' + i + '"] :radio[value="' + variant.options[i] +'"]');

var radioButtonMobileSticky = mobileStickyAtc.find('.swatch-dropdown__sliding-option-selector-outer-container[data-option-index="' + i + '"] :radio[value="' + variant.options[i] +'"]');

radioButtonSticky.get(0).checked = true;
radioButtonMobileSticky.get(0).checked = true;
```

In the example above, only the 'radioButtonMobileSticky' input gets checked.
However, if I switched the order of the last two lines of this code, only the 'radioButtonSticky' input gets checked.

I haven't seen any answers for why this might be happening online and I'm going insane! Any help appreciated!

I expect both inputs to be checked regardless of the order that the JavaScript/JQuery 'checks' theme.

Comment: `:radio` is for radio buttons.  It's a specific UX that only allows one (within the group) to be selected at a time.   Consider `(o) Yes ( ) No` - you only want yes *or* no selected, not both.   Another distinction between radios and checkboxes is that you can't "uncheck" a radio.    If you want both selectable, then **do not use radios.**  Or, ensure they are in different radio groups.  Without HTML, it's impossible to tell your intent.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see in your snippet: this case may happen because you are using `input[type="radio"]` instead of `input[type="checkbox"]`.

**Only one radio button in a given group can be selected at the same time.**
[Check MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

You should consider using checkbox instead of radio inputs.

Have a good day!

Comment: Ah yes, this will 100% be it. I think what I’ll need to do is keep them as radio inputs (which they need to be), but change the name of one of them so they are not in the same group, so that they can both selected. Thanks for your help!